# How do I get a home bar on iPad 9?

Tags: ipad

I have a home bar whenever I open a slide over window, and I find it really nice. Can I get this home bar on the iPad itself? [image]

On the iPad [image]

Answer (score 0):

A [9th generation iPad](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-10-2-inch-9th-gen-2021-a2602-wi-fi-only-specs.html) has a Home button, it doesn’t display or need a home bar on the “main” screen.